# Dropdown list for reporting hierarchy data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have two tables reporting,employee_details
reporting contains suprvisor_id,subordinate_id fields which are emp_id in employee_details table .And reporting table contains three levels (supervisors->subordinates->subordinates->employees) and i want to show this data as dropdown by fetching name from employee_details table, as hierarchy .so please help me is there any way to do it?

Comment: do you have problems with your query? I suppose supervisor_id is 0 or NULL if the employee is in Top-Level, isn't it?

Comment: no that is not a problem displaying that hierarchy as dropdown is my problem

Comment: So if you know definitely that there are only 3 Levels there is a fast way with one query to get the hole tree. If you have N levels, I think you have to do many queries recoursiv.

Comment: So, you have your hole tree already in an array?

Comment: ya.I have only three levels and i want to know if there are more three levels also

Comment: no but i know how to get each level but using that multiple queries forming tree iam not able to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defititly need to get the hole tree in an array if you want to display it. And this is a little bit tricky.

I think you arent't really shure how many levels you have in tree.
So the simplest way is the following but in big trees it have a bad performance. When the tree grows really big you need to check other technics.

The following is fast written, not tested an could have some bugs. But I post it to show you a possible solution:

```
<?php

class tree {

    private $level = 0;

    public function getChildsRecoursive($parentid=0,$recoursive=false) {
        // you would have your own db object... please replace this...
        $db->select("select * from reporting r JOIN employee_details d ON(r.subordinate_id=d.emp_id) where supervisor_id='$parentid' ORDER BY d.name");
        $r = array();
        while($data = $db->fetchArray()) {
            $sid = $data['supervisor_id'];
            $cid = $data['subordinate_id'];
            if($recoursive) {
                $this->level++;
                $data['level'] = $this->level;
                $data['childs'] = $this->getChildsRecoursive($cid, true);
                $this->level--;
            }
            $r[] = $data;
        }
        return $r;
    }

    public function getDropdown() {
            // I suspect the top Level have a supervisor_id = 0
        $data = $this->getChildsRecoursive(0,true);
            // you can do a print_r($data) here to see if the results are correct

        $r = "<select>";
        foreach($data as $d) {
            $r .= $this->getOptionsRecoursive($d);
        }
        $r .= "</select>";
            return $r;
    }

    public function getOptionsRecoursive($data) {
          $r = "<option>";
          for($i=0;$i<$data['level'];$i++) {
            $r .= "&nbsp;";
          }
          $r .= $data['name'];
          $r .= "</option>\n";

          if(isset($data['childs'])) {
            foreach($data['childs'] as $c) {
                $r .= $this->getOptionsRecoursive($c);
            }
          }
          return $r;
    }

}
    ?>
```

Hope it helps to understand. (Please recognize that this will cause many queries depending on how big your tree is).

To Start you need to do

```
$tree = new tree();
echo $tree->getDropdown();
```